# Merge colour of zero value points from visualisation field to background colour in Paraview

Tags: visualization, paraview, computation, fluid-dynamics

I use Paraview to visualise flow field. The data is rescaled in the range [-a, a] as the picture shown. [image: Flow field visualisation] In this case, points with non-zero value only occur in the middle and most of points are with zero value. I would like to ask for help how can I set those points with zero value (grey) to have the same colour with background (blue).

Answer (score 1):

You can use opacity mapping to map zero value to opacity = 0. From **Color Map Editor**, check **Enable opacity mapping for surfaces**. Then edit the opacity transfer function on the panel to get a suitable mapping.